# MS Train Simulator timing issues

Tags: technical-issues, microsoft-train-simulator

Microsoft Train Simulator has apparently an issue with timing. It gives running time-of-day clock, but the more stations I have to stop at, the more it becomes off. For instance, I were to stop at the station at 14:22:09. By my clock I am arriving late at 14:24:20. However, as I initiate the loading/unloading of passengers, it records my arrival time as 14:19:41. It tends to accumulate, and during one hour run the error goes up to the magnitude of four to six minutes. And that is very significant as to keep on schedule one has to constantly calculate average speed necessary to arrive at the station at certain time.

Is that a known bug, or something rare? Is it platform or system specific problem (I run the game under WinE set as Windows 7)? Is it fixed with some sort of patch? I had read about editing `default.wag` settings file, as it appears that the game by default uses different values for on-track and off-track so-called time step (10 and 30 ms, respectively). Apparently, off-track time step manages parked train (load/unload, or stopping at the signal), and also the scenery, and that is why on slower machines one would want off-track to be less precise, as it loads the processor too much.

One solution would be to match both on- and off-track time step values, but I would like to understand more how are those used exactly, how low ore high I should go when setting those numbers, what is difference in time solver methods (Euler and Runge-Kutta), and why by default both use different methods?

Comment: Just get Train Simulator 2013

Comment: Are you by any chance launching the game with C:\\path\to\train.exe _/timeacceleration_ flag? Check [this link](http://www.dieselswest.com/MSTSExtras.htm) out